# ASP.NET Core Web API: The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'System.ServiceModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add an ASP.NET Core Web API to my application, so external apps can query its in-memory data, although its complaining about missing files on my system.

I installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost` package and added this code:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");
```

Now I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

If I install package `System.ServiceModel.Primitives`, then I get:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.10.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

If I install `System.ServiceModel.Http` then I get:

> Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no the `System.ServiceModel.dll` version currently for the ASP.NET-Core that contain the `HostNameComparisonMode` type.

If you go to [HostNameComparisonMode Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.hostnamecomparisonmode?viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) page in the Microsoft documentation and select `.NET 5`, for example, you will receive the following message:

> The requested page is not available for **.NET 5**. You have been
> redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

The same for .NET 6/7/8.

---

*NOTE: If you will compile the a project for the .Net Framework 4.8 than the following declaration will appear in the `System.ServiceModel.dll`:*

[image]